# Site analytics legends display partly in Cyrillic (Russian?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, languages, site-analytics

This morning I earned the [Access to Site Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) privilege.

Naturally, I headed over to [the analytics page](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) (only accessible if you have 25K or greater reputation) only to find that some of the legend labels are in Cyrillic:

[image]

Google Translate detects the language as Russian.

The behaviour appears to be consistent in Chromium and Firefox on Ubuntu 15.10 and Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 14.04) as well as on Gnome Web (previously called Epiphany) on Arch Linux.

I imagine this is a bug?

Comment: Да, that's definitely Russian.

Comment: I, For One, Welcome Our New Russian Overlords.

Comment: Are you in Russia, i.e. do you have an IP address that Google thinks belongs to Russia?

Comment: @RobertLongson, I would be very surprised if that were the case. I live in a highly populated, predominantly English-speaking part of Canada.

Comment: Yup this is a bug, it popped up because someone ran the analytics for SO on the ruSO site which is cached and reared its head on the English side. The text should be fixed at this time while the devs dig deeper into a fix.

Comment: Cyrillic? Maybe it's an invasion of the [Mongolian language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273536/is-there-a-secret-fake-mongolian-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fix for this was rolled out yesterday thanks to [Michael Stum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum).