# Why did I receive a notification in some foreign language?

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

Today I reached the 25k milestone. I received a message about that in my inbox. Normally this message is:

> You've earned the "Access to site analytics" privilege!
> Learn more about it in the help center.

However, the first time (and only the first time) that I consulted my inbox, the second line (and only the second line) read:

> Узнайте больше об этом в справочном центре.

... or something similar because I had to resort to Google Translate for the purpose of asking this question.

How is it possible that I received a notification (partly) in a foreign language that I don't know at all?

This [six year old question that apparantly got resolved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327493/site-analytics-legends-display-partly-in-cyrillic-russian) deals with something vaguely similar.

Comment: Blimey, of all the places for Russia to interfere

Comment: Given that we have [SO in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), I'm not really worried @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica.  Now, if the message appeared in leetspeek...

Comment: Likely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416726

Comment: Already reported and [tag:status-review]: [Wrong language in recent achievements](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/289905).

Comment: d00d! \v/47 4b0u7 574ck 0\/3rfl0w 1n 1337?