# Answer sorting buttons are now in Portuguese

Tags: bug, sorting

Meta is unaffected but sorting buttons on Main are now in Portuguese for me for all questions that have answers.

It's not just Stack Overflow, all sites sorting is in Portuguese although presumably that's not actually a problem for Stack Overflow in Portuguese.

I noticed this in Firefox (98.0.1) at first but Chrome is just the same.

Here's a screenshot taken from a Stack Overflow post.

[image: Sorting buttons in Portuguese]

Comment: No repro for me.

Comment: Perhaps I'm in group C of the [A/B sorting test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416486/announcing-an-a-b-test-for-a-trending-sort-option/416612#416612).

Comment: Likely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416725

Comment: So interestingly the opposite is true for me the foreign language sites have the sort buttons in English. I assume that's not supposed to be the case ([pt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhE6t.png), [jp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5yO8.png), [ru](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02t5e.png), [es](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycvE6.png)).

Comment: No repro either (Chrome on android). Just to be sure - browser and version?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Tried Firefox first and then switched to Chrome in case there was some cookie effect. Both browsers have the same issue and unlike Henry, Stack Overflow in Portuguese is in Portuguese and not English.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks. Huh, weird. Oddly coincides with another bug of a similar nature mentioned by CertainPerformance