# Why is there some Russian text in achievement notifications?

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog, internationalization, localization

I saw that I had some achievements and when I went to check, I see that it has a part of the text in Russian. Why is this happening? I don't really speak Russian, so would have never set this myself. Looks like here in the Meta site it is actually showing fine in English, but on the Stack Overflow page it is in Russian. There doesn't seem to be any place to configure this.

Main Stack Overflow:

[image: Screenshot in Stack Overflow]

Stack Overflow meta:

[image: Screenshot in Stack Overflow Meta]

Comment: No repro for me (from Japan). It's probably caching. Related old bug report on meta.se: [Wrong language in recent achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/756727)

Comment: I'd doubt that there would be a setting for "I want half of my messages to be in another language" :)

Comment: @GinoMempin caching *what*? why is only half the message cached? "Caching" is acting as a thought-terminating cliche here

Comment: Vaguely similar: [Site analytics legends display partly in Cyrillic (Russian?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327493/5320906).

Comment: @user253751 See response of former staff here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235277/756727.

Comment: Have you ever visited a Stack Exchange site which was in Russian or with your browser language defaulted to Russian?

Comment: @user253751 the trouble with Stack Overflow is that what is a running gag or a cliche everywhere else, here it is a reality... Huge site, huge database, lots of automated processes, lots of opportunity for clashes / race conditions.

Comment: @TravisJ I experienced this same error and I had not.

Comment: @TravisJ not that I can remember, but I can't rule it out for certain

Comment: Just had this same error happen to me. Part russian/english on SO: https://gyazo.com/59c53b2641579c8c45d60123ea581a54.
Works fine on SO Meta: https://gyazo.com/5bb4f53c016a6468f4ff7a437b2e0c32