# Why is my reopen queue completion notification written in Russian?

Tags: bug, status-review, notifications, localization

For the following post: [How to get messages in a channel in pycord and then delete them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454515/how-to-get-messages-in-a-channel-in-pycord-and-then-delete-them)  (don't worry about the issues with this post; I'm currently trying to fix my duplicate. A lot of people viewed the post and I think it helped some people)

I just saw the following in my inbox:

[image: Image of Russian question update]

I put it in [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) and it translates to the following:

> Previous edits did not help reopen the issue. You can make other edits.

What am I supposed to do when I see this? Is this an automated response, or did someone actually type this out?

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Why is there some Russian text in achievement notifications?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422735/2821954). Known "regular" issue.

Comment: You edited the question apparently petitioning to have it reopened because you don't think the duplicates address the question. This petition was declined and the question was left closed. This message is automated; however, it was supposed to be in English.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So this is automated? I'll change this to a bug tag then. Thanks!

Comment: I'm [status-review]ing this separately from the other russian text in notification bug reports. While it's _likely_ that it's related to (or exactly the same as) the issues [reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/1099857) and [here on MSO](/q/422735/15497888) both of those are about achievement notifications specifically and it's not possible without access to the code responsible to determine for certain whether or not a fix on that notification type would also resolve this issue.

Comment: Also, this post is currently primarily a bug report about an incorrect russian localisation applied to your notification about reopen queue. If you're looking for specific support from the community on the duplicate closure of your question or the targets used please ask a _separate question_ here on MSO which focuses on that topic.